# How to port Scala 2.7.7 code that uses scala.collection.jcl to Scala 2.8?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I've got some code that references scala.collection.jcl written against Scala 2.7.7.  I'm now trying to compile it against Scala 2.8 for the first time, and I'm getting this error:

"value jcl is not a member of package collection".

Is there a substitute/replacement for jcl in 2.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like JavaConversions does the job somewhat:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```